# Cross-referencing within table with set numbers

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I need to reference in table cell to another cell in another table. In both cells should be exhibited a number - the same number (once as a plain text inserted by me and once as a cross reference).

I tried the following, but  in the output the reference doesn't show the number I set (i.e. '1' in the firs cell of the second table), but the chapter the table is in (i.e. '1.1' in the first cell of the first table).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{0,8cm} | p{2,5cm} p{1,8cm} p{2,3cm} p{2,6cm}  | p{0,7cm} | }


  \caption{Coding frames for`ask (for)'}
  \label{table:Coding_frames_verb}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\textbf{\#} &   \textbf{Coding frame}&&& &  \textbf{f}\\
\hline
\ref{cf_1} & V.ACT.sbj[A] &[A]-NOM&[AD]-ACC & &11 \\
 \hline
2 & V.ACT.sbj[A] &[A]-NOM&[AD/T]-ACC && 1\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{small}

\chapter{example of chapter}


\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{0,3cm}  p{2,4cm} p{1,5cm} p{2,4cm}  p{0,5cm}   p{4cm} | }
\hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{Coding frame} &&& \textbf{f} &    \textbf{Passage in the Qur'an}\\ 

1\label{cf_1} & V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [AD]-ACC & 11 &    2:108:4, 2:273:20,  7:6:5, 7:187:24, 9:65:2, 12:82:1, 16:43:9, 21:7:8, 23:113:7, 33:53:42, 55:29:1 \\ 

2&  V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [AD/T]-ACC  &1 &   70:10:2 \\
3&V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [UTT/T]-ACC& 1&  5:102:2\\

4&  V.ACT.sbj[A]&  [A]-NOM & [REQ]INDF.PRO &    1&  2:61:36\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Please try to minimize your example. All this `longtable` and `small` an so on is just adding noise to your question. Better show us two minimal tables and then a second example which shows the desired output (hard coded) you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % take a look on the corners of your tables. 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{0,8cm} | p{2,5cm} p{1,8cm} p{2,3cm} p{2,6cm}  | p{0,7cm} | }         
        \caption{Coding frames for`ask (for)'}\label{table:Coding_frames_verb}
        \endfirsthead
        \hline
        \textbf{\#} &   \textbf{Coding frame}&&& &  \textbf{f}\\
        \hline
        \hyperref[cf_1]{1} & V.ACT.sbj[A] &[A]-NOM&[AD]-ACC & &11 \\
        \hline
        2 & V.ACT.sbj[A] &[A]-NOM&[AD/T]-ACC && 1\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\chapter{example of chapter}    
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{0,3cm}  p{2,4cm} p{1,5cm} p{2,4cm}  p{0,5cm}   p{4cm} | }
        \hline
        \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Coding frame} &&& \textbf{f} &    \textbf{Passage in the Qur'an}\\ 
        1\label{cf_1} & V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [AD]-ACC & 11 &    2:108:4, 2:273:20,  7:6:5, 7:187:24, 9:65:2, 12:82:1, 16:43:9, 21:7:8, 23:113:7, 33:53:42, 55:29:1 \\ 
        2&  V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [AD/T]-ACC  &1 &   70:10:2 \\
        3&V.ACT.sbj[A] & [A]-NOM & [UTT/T]-ACC& 1&  5:102:2\\
        4&  V.ACT.sbj[A]&  [A]-NOM & [REQ]INDF.PRO &    1&  2:61:36\\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

Please add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble. It will show you that both tables are too wide. Why don't you use `l` columns instead?

Comment: thank you! Exactly like this! And what do you mean by '1 columns'?

Comment: @csilla you are welcome. Not 1, l. Left aligned columns. E.g. `\begin{longtable}{|l|*{4}{l}|l|} `. Just try them, it will look much better. And you safe a lot of hard coded column width definitions. If you want to set any table width by hand, you could stick to Word :-)

Comment: ok, I shall try. You are right! I'm a beginner so I am grateful for any improvement!

Comment: @csilla The second table could be `\begin{longtable}{|lllll>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{3.9cm}|}` and maybe you set "Coding frame" in a `\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Coding frame}}`

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. My table in my real document is a lot longer and the columns in the other rows are far wider, so your suggestion works only  for the rows that have a similar with.  And I shall try your other code as well - the other table is not so big. Thanks again!